# Make docker-swarm update from ECR

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

How can I make docker-swarm connect to ECR and update the current container with the latest image. If yes, please share with an article where can I start my investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On whichever node you're using to control your docker swarm, log into ECR and pull the latest image, with this command: `eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region <whatever-your-region-is>)`

This will log in to your ECR registry. Note that you'll need to add your AWS access key and secret key to this node for this to work; if you haven't done this already, do so with the `aws configure` command.

Now, when you run `docker stack deploy` to start your container(s), add the `--with-registry-auth` flag to the command: this "spreads" the login to all the nodes in your swarm so they can all download the image.

Comment: Thanks, that something I can start investigation at.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need two things

1. Login to AWS ECR (Tokens are valid for 12 hours only)

   eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region region-name)
2. Update your docker services

   docker service update -d -q --with-registry-auth service-name

**Note:** Make sure in your service definition the docker image has the suffix latest. e.g. `docker_image_name:latest`

**[This article](http://issamben.com/docker-swarm-ecr-auto-login/)** describes exactly how to automatically login to AWS ECR and update docker services.

http://issamben.com/docker-swarm-ecr-auto-login/